# How to use the controller property of a view

Tags: ember.js

Should I pass a variable that extend from a controller ? A string referencing the class that extend a controller ? An instance of the controller ?

If it's a subview, how to settup parent controller ?

For reference, please see the [Documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#property_controller).

Comment: are you asking how to access a property of a controller from the view? eg http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kumaxihi/1/edit

Comment: No. I'm asking how to setup the controller of a view using the controller property documented in the link I gave. And I'm doing that because I'm creating a subview inside a view.

Answer (score 1):

The subview will automatically inherit the controller of the parent view, if however you need to associate it with an instance of another controller it is best to associate the other controller with the controller of the parent view. 
Example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kumaxihi/2/edit

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs:["oneOther"],
  prop1:"this is prop1",
  prop2:"this is prop2",
  prop3:"this is prop3"
});

App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
 prop1OfController:Ember.computed.alias("controller.prop1"),
  prop2OfController:function(){
    return this.get("controller.prop2");
  }.property()

});

App.RandomSubView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:"random-sub-view",
  prop3OfController:Ember.computed.alias("controller.prop3"),
  thePropOfAnotherController:Ember.computed.alias("controller.controllers.oneOther.theProp")
});

App.OneOtherController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  theProp:"this is the prop of the other controller"
});
```

If however you want to set the `controller` property directly, you would do something like `this.set("controller",theControllerInstance)`. Now the controller instance would have to be available somehow, for example either via the routing hierarchy or from association of parent controllers or even via the `render` function of the `route` (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/).